# Access property value after setting it with setNativeProps

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to toggle the display of dynamically created components in React Native (with Coffeescript). The components are created conform the structure of a JSON object and each component has a `ref` attribute with the according `id` so i can access the specific component like so: `this.refs[ id ]`

I have the following function to change the display of the component

```
changeDisplay: ( id ) ->
  this.refs[ id ].setNativeProps( {
    display: 'flex'
  } );
```

This works fine when i want to change the initial display, but i want to toggle the display between `none` and `flex` (based on the current state).

Because i don't know how many items are rendered on forehand i can't (or don't know how to) define states for them.

I tried the following, but i somehow can't get the new display state back after setting it with `setNativeProps()`

```
changeDisplay: ( id ) ->
  if this.refs[ id ].props.style.display is 'none'
    this.refs[ id ].setNativeProps( {
      display: 'flex'
    } );
  else
    this.refs[ id ].setNativeProps( {
      display: 'none'
    } );
```

Initially `this.refs[ id ].props.style.display` returns the state the component is in when i load the view (= `none`), but after i run the function above the display state is visually changed (the component shows up), but `this.refs[ id ].props.style.display` still return the initial state `none`

Why?

**EDIT:**

Below is my (stripped) component (as requested). I want to toggle the display of the child tasks in a certain project. So if i tap the project `Project 1`, i want to toggle the display state of the tasks 1 & 2.

```
import React from 'react';

import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Icon,
} from 'react-native-elements';

class ListTasks extends React.Component

  constructor: ( props ) ->
    super props

    this.data =
      list: [
        {
          id: 1
          name: 'Project 1'
          type: 'project'
          parent: null
        },{
          id: 2
          parent: 1
          name: 'Task 1'
          type: 'task'
        },{
          id: 3
          parent: 1
          name: 'Task 2'
          type: 'task'
        },{
          id: 4
          name: 'Project 2'
          type: 'project'
          parent: null
        },{
          id: 5
          parent: 4
          name: 'Task 3'
          type: 'task'
        },{
          id: 6
          parent: 4
          name: 'Task 4'
          type: 'task'
        }
      ]

  toggleDisplay: ( id ) ->
    if this.refs[ id ].props.style.display is v[ 0 ]
      this.refs[ id ].setNativeProps( {
        display: 'flex'
      } );
    else
      this.refs[ id ].setNativeProps( {
        display: 'none'
      } );

  renderList: ( data ) ->
    <View>
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.toggleDisplay( data.id )}>
          <Text>{data.name}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <View ref={data.id} style={display: 'none'}>
        { this.renderTask cor for cor in this.data.list when cor.parent is data.id }
      </View>
    </View>

  renderTask: ( data ) ->
    <View>
      <Text>{data.name}</Text>
    </View>

  render: ->
    <View>
      <ScrollView style={height:'100%'}>
        { this.data.list.map( ( data ) =>
          if data.type == 'project'
            this.renderList( data )
        ) }
      </ScrollView>
    </View>

export default ListTasks
```

Comment: Can you add in the components and explain what you are trying to hide?

Comment: @riwu see my post, i added the (stripped) component

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is not very optimal for storing data that clearly has a 2D sectional kind of relationships. I have modified the data structure a bit below.

DOM manipulation is also not the React way. Instead we use states to manage the visibility and properties of the elements.

A working example of a sectional collapsible list:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, SectionList } from 'react-native';

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Project 1',
    type: 'project',
    data: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Task 1',
        type: 'task',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Task 2',
        type: 'task',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Project 2',
    type: 'project',
    data: [
      {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Task 3',
        type: 'task',
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        name: 'Task 4',
        type: 'task',
      },
    ],
  },
];

class ListTasks extends React.Component {
  state = {
    list: data,
    show: {},
  };

  render() {
    // SectionList is used instead of ScrollView as it has better performance
    return (
      <SectionList
        style={{ marginTop: 50 }}
        sections={this.state.list}
        renderItem={({ item, section }) =>
          // render null if show state for the section is falsy
          (this.state.show[section.id] ? <Text style={{ padding: 10 }}>{item.name}</Text> : null)
        }
        renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{ paddingVertical: 10, margin: 10, backgroundColor: 'grey' }}
            onPress={() =>
              this.setState((prevState) => ({
                show: {
                  ...prevState.show,
                  // toggle the show state for the seciton
                  [section.id]: !prevState.show[section.id],
                },
              }))
            }
          >
            <Text>{section.name}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default ListTasks;
```